# Firefox slow on page with many iframe

Tags: firefox, iframe

I have about 10+ iframes in a page, and it's slowing down Firefox3.6.x substantially.

Is there anything I can do about this? i.e. modify the DOM somehow, or suspending certain events etc etc ?

Comment: Wow, care to comment on why you need that many iframes?

Comment: I am loading all my bookmarks into a page with iframes (instead of into tabs)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a javascript solution instead..

http://www.tosbourn.com/2009/11/development/inframe-dynamic-iframe-creation-with-jquery/

It might be slightly faster, although the viewport for all your sites must be tiny?

Comment: yes the viewport is tiny, but there is a button to maximize it per iframe. I don't think the jQuery solution will help though. If there is a way to pause the iframes..(keep it from refreshing)..